# Alternative word for exploitation?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I am a reading a book of economics, I came across this phrase(Paraphrasing)

> Due to the improvement in infrastructure in the city, the market is ripe with opportunities, which can be **exploited** by out of city businessmen.

Exploitation has negative connotation attached to it. Hence, could somebody recommend an alternative word/expression.

I looked up the thesaurus, and couldn't find any word that would make sense in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Thesaurus gives plenty, but it may be easier to use them in an active clause:

> ... which out-of-city businessmen can /take advantage of/capitalise on/benefit from/put to good use etc.

The use of passive voice with these phrasal verbs tends to be awkward, so it's best to use active.